# JQuery mobile popup does not always come up once pressing related buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, focus

In my mobile app I have two buttons next to each other which relate to the same popup.

After clicking on the `first` button, the popup opens with a message (data-code attribute). Then, after clicking on the `second` button (to close the popup), the popup will not be opened again (with another message) after clicking on that `second` button again. The button looks like to be selected, and the popup will only open again once the user takes the focus off the button and then presses it again.

It works good in a situation where you close the popup without clicking on the `second` button.

My buttons have the following properties:

```
role = null;
icon = 'grid';
rel = 'popup';
```

The html changes once a button is clicked:

```
$( this.selector ).off( "tap" ).on( "tap", ".ui-icon-grid", function() {
    $( "#popup" ).html( $( this ).attr( "data-code" ) );
} );
```

This issue only happens on a mobile device.

Tested this issue on `https://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/` by duplicating the `Open Popup` button, and the same issue occurs sometimes. (on my mobile device)

Should I use multiple popups instead of relating all buttons to one popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I prevented the default JQuery mobile event from happening and I take it over from there. This prevents the strange behaviour from happening. A better solution is still welcome.

```
event.preventDefault();
var $popup = $( "#popoup" );
var $button = $( this );
var buttonOffset= $button.offset();
var buttonCenterY = buttonOffset.top + ( $button.height() / 2 );
var buttonCenterX = buttonOffset.left + ( $button.width() / 2 );
$popup.html( $button.attr( "data-code" ) );
$popup.popup( "open", { x: buttonCenterX, y: buttonCenterY } );
```